# How to remove first character in the first column from each row in CSV file?

Tags: windows, powershell, replace

My CSV file has column headers, then for each rows after that, the first character in the first column starts with "+".

How can I remove the first character "+" on the 1st column from each row (other than the first header row) ?
Thank you.

Sample file:

```
"col1","col2","col3"...
+"datacol1a","datacol2a","datacol3a"
+"datacol1b","datacol2b","datacol3b"
+"datacol1c","datacol2c","datacol3c"
```

Desired result:

```
"col1","col2","col3"...
"datacol1a","datacol2a","datacol3a"
"datacol1b","datacol2b","datacol3b"
"datacol1c","datacol2c","datacol3c"
```

I tried this powershell code (FindReplace.ps1), but it doesn't work:

```
param([string]$CSVFile="c:\myfolder\myCsv.csv")
(gc $CSVFile) -replace "^+"
```

If I use this powershell code, it also delete the first character on the header row (which I don't want to do). How can I do this, except for the header row (row 1) ?

```
Get-Content -Path $CSVFile | ForEach-Object { $_.substring(1,$_.Length - 1) }
```

I call this powershell code from a BAT file

```
powershell -file FindReplace.ps1 -CSVFile "c:\myfolder\myCsv.csv" > 
"c:\myfolder\myCsv2.csv"
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please copy and paste as text the code you are trying to make work.

Comment: Hi, I just edit my earlier post with what I tried. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the -replace uses regex, you need to escape the + sign. Its a special character. And you need to tell the script what you want to replace it with. 
Try this:

`(Get-Content .\csv1.csv) -replace ('^\+', '') | Out-File .\csv2.csv`

This could be another solution.

```
$csv = get-Content C:\Temp\csv1.csv
$header = $csv | Select-Object -First 1
$data = $csv | Select-Object -skip 1 |  ForEach-Object { $_.substring(1, 
$_.Length - 1) }
$($header; $data) | Set-Content -Path C:\Temp\csv2.csv
```

Edited to add @TheMadTechnician solution.

```
 Get-Content C:\Temp\text.csv| ForEach-Object {$_.trimstart('+')} | set-content c:\temp\csv232.csv
```

I left out the alias for ease of reading

Comment: This would replace all '+' characters in the file. There might be some in the data that should be kept. `(Get-Content .\csv1.csv) -replace ('^\+', '') | Out-File .\csv2.csv`

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to replace all '+' characters in the file. 
I only want to replace character '+' that's in the first character of the first column, and not on the header row (row 1).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Ill edit my post to add another solution.

Comment: @lit You do not need the parenthesis around the replace parameters in, and if you are replacing it with nothing you can leave the last part off, so that part can be reduced from `-replace ('^\+','')` to simply `-replace '^\+'`.

Comment: @Anders The substring method doesn't require the second parameter if you are going to continue to the end of the line, so that can be simplified to `$_.substring(1)`. Possibly a better way to do it would be the `TrimStart()` method, since then you don't have to split the header out to its own thing, and it can just be 1 line: `gc C:\Temp\csv1.csv|%{$_.trimstart('+')}|set-content c:\temp\csv2.csv`

Comment: The first solution would remove a '+' as the first character on the header row. Is that a real problem? Most column names would not begin with a '+' character.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thanks. I didnt know about that you could skip the last part if you skip with nothing. I would still keep the it all ind the -replace, just because i find it easier to read. But that´s a personal preference

Comment: Thank you Anders and all who replied.
This solution works:
Get-Content C:\Temp\text.csv| ForEach-Object {$_.trimstart('+')} | set-content c:\temp\csv232.csv